# Hdfs file access in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-submit

I am developing an application , where I read a file from hadoop, process and store the data back to hadoop. 
I am confused what should be the proper hdfs file path format. When reading a hdfs file from spark shell like

```
val file=sc.textFile("hdfs:///datastore/events.txt")
```

it works fine and I am able to read it.

But when I sumbit the jar to yarn which contains same set of code it is giving the error saying

```
org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Uri without authority: hdfs:/datastore/events.txt
```

When I add name node ip as `hdfs://namenodeserver/datastore/events.txt` everything works.

I am bit confused about the behaviour and need an guidance.

**Note: I am using aws emr set up and all the configurations are default.**

Comment: do you have `fs.defaultFS` set in your `core-site.xml`?

Comment: Yes it is set and pointing to master instance

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use sc.textFile("hdfs://...") you need to give the full path(absolute path), in your example that would be "nn1home:8020/.."

If you want to make it simple, then just use sc.textFile("hdfs:/input/war-and-peace.txt")

That's only one /

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate a bit. I have tried hdfs:/// and this doesn't works. But from the spark shell it does. So, providing name node is absolute mandatory?

Comment: Instead of 3 times "///" please try with 1 time "/" without namenode option it will work. see my example and try.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. As I debugged further `fs.defaultFS` property was not used from `core-site.xml` when I just pass path as `hdfs:///path/to/file`. But all the hadoop config properties are loaded (as I logged the `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` object.

As a work around I manually read the property as `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().get("fs.defaultFS)` and appended this in the path.

I don't know is it a correct way of doing it.